# mysql date to be added dynamically by passing paramters

Tags: mysql

Hi i need a mysql query for the following scenario

my table contains below column **(no date column in my table)**

```
id  name

1   xxx

2   yyy

3   zzz
```

parmaters- from date(13-11-2017) and to date (16-11-2017)

```
ouput
====

name date

xxx  13-11-2017

xxx  14-11-2017

xxx  15-11-2017

xxx  16-11-2017

yyy  13-11-2017

yyy  14-11-2017

yyy  15-11-2017

yyy  16-11-2017

zzz  13-11-2017

zzz  14-11-2017

zzz  15-11-2017

zzz  16-11-2017
```

please help.

Thanks in advance

Raja

Comment: name join with date

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I cross join the date to a selection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613189/how-do-i-cross-join-the-date-to-a-selection)